# Why is the size() of a HashMap unreliable sometimes?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I've been working on a Leetcode problem which is to sort an array of integers on the # of bits. I've implemented the code below and it works for most of the cases but there are some really large test cases that for some reason aren't correct.

```java
public int[] sortByBits(int[] arr) {
  HashMap < Integer, Integer > map = new HashMap < > ();
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String binary_val = Integer.toBinaryString(arr[i]);
    int bit_count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < binary_val.length(); j++) {
      if (binary_val.charAt(j) == '1') {
        bit_count++;
      }
    }
    map.put(arr[i], bit_count);
  }
  //Here is the problem
  for (int l = 0; l < map.size(); l++) {
    for (int k = l + 1; k < map.size(); k++) {
      if (map.get(arr[l]) > map.get(arr[k])) {
        int temp = arr[l];
        arr[l] = arr[k];
        arr[k] = temp;
      } else if (map.get(arr[l]) == map.get(arr[k])) {
        if (arr[l] > arr[k]) {
          int temp = arr[l];
          arr[l] = arr[k];
          arr[k] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

The problem lies in me using map.size() in the for loops to iterate through the map and sort the elements. However, when I change map.size to arr.length the code works flawlessly. But map.size should be the same as arr.length as for each element in the array is being used as a key. Can someone please explain why this is the case? Should I just refrain from using the size() of HashMaps entirely?

Comment: Are the incoming values in `arr` guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: And why would you use `Map.size()` when you could use `arr.length` anyway?

Comment: by the way, check the `Integer.bitCount()` method....

Comment: \(and you *must* use `arr.length` is you want to sort the elements of `arr`; `map.size()` should be used to iterate through the `map`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you use `map.size()` as the condition for your loops, especially when sorting. When you use `map.size()`, you are iterating through the map's unique keys, which may or may not be the same as the length of the original array `arr`. Because keys in a HashMap are unique, if you have multiple values in your `arr` array, the matching keys in the map will overwrite each other.